# Can you create a PIL image with Cython without copying memory redundantly?

Tags: python, camera, usb, python-imaging-library, cython

I am using Cython to grab images from a USB camera and convert them into a PIL image that is returned to the caller.

The data for the image is in a character array pointed at by the "convert_buffer" member of the structure returned by the image grabbing function:

```
struct FlyCaptureImage:
   /// stuff
  char * convert_buffer
   /// more stuff
```

Right now, I am doing this to turn it into a PIL image:

```
cdef unsigned char *convert_buffer
cdef Py_ssize_t byte_length
cdef bytes py_string

// get the number of bytes into a Py_ssize_t type
byte_length = count

// slice the char array so it looks like a Python str type
py_string = convert_buffer[:byte_length]

// create the PIL image from the python string
pil_image = PILImage.fromstring('RGB', (width, height), py_string)
```

That procedure of converting the data into a python string takes 2ms for what sounds like it could be a zero-copy event.  Is it possible to get PIL to create my image just from the char * image data pointer that the camera API provided?

Comment: Why did you accept the answer if it does not answer what you (and right now, me :-)  ) was looking for?

Comment: I went ahead and did it because FogleBird (the guy who put up the bounty) awarded the bounty, even though the question wasn't answered.

Comment: (I'm not sure why he did that, BTW)

Comment: BTW, I researched a little on the question, but it ended up the library I was wrappign required me to create the intermediate buffer all the same. (Its render function returns a buffer with only one scanline at a time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of PIL 1.1.4, the [`Image.frombuffer`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) method supports zero-copy:

> Creates an image memory from pixel data in a string or buffer object,
>   using the standard "raw" decoder. For some modes, the image memory
>   will share memory with the original buffer (this means that changes to
>   the original buffer object are reflected in the image). Not all modes
>   can share memory; supported modes include "L", "RGBX", "RGBA", and
>   "CMYK".

The problem is that your camera data appears to be 24-bit RGB, where PIL wants 32-bit RGBA/RGBX.  Can you control the pixel format coming from the camera API?

<strike>If not, there still may be an advantage to using `Image.frombuffer`, since it will accept a `buffer` instead of requiring you to build a python string from the pixel data.</strike>

Edit: looking at the source for `frombuffer`, it is a light wrapper on `fromstring`, and zero-copy requires a pixel format in the `Image._MAPMODES` list (i.e. RGBX).  At a minimum, you would have to copy/convert the RGB data to an RGBX buffer to get a zero-copy compatible pixel format.

I don't have a better way to get the raw bytes into PIL, but here are some interesting references:

- [Cython automatic type conversions](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#automatic-type-conversions)
- [Efficient indexing of objects supporting the Python buffer interface](http://wiki.cython.org/enhancements/buffer) (for numpy/PIL)
- [Converting malloc'ed buffers from C to Python without copy using Cython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284260/converting-malloced-buffers-from-c-to-python-without-copy-using-cython)
- [PyMemoryView_FromMemory (python 3.3)](http://docs.python.org/dev/c-api/memoryview.html#PyMemoryView_FromMemory)

Comment: Any idea how I create something in Cython that lets me use the data buffer pointed at in the camera struct (the cdef char * convert_buffer in the example) as a `buffer` object in Python?

I've been looking at `Image.frombuffer`, `Image.fromstring`, and even `Image.fromarray` and I can't seem to find the right pieces to glue it all together through Cython

Comment: To clarify, the main issue isn't PIL's copy, it's the Cython copy that I have to do to get the data into a form that it will pass to PIL Image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the way to go isto manually assemble a Python String, or array.array Object - using the C struct for it, and pointing the buffer to your data. As I did not need it at all, I did not went so far as to write the code for it.

Just checked it - it is not possible with strings - the strign body must be allocated in a single piece with the string-object headers (there is not a pointer to another chunk of memory).