# Pass a cython allocated buffer to python

Tags: python, memory-management, cython

I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284260/converting-malloced-buffers-from-c-to-python-without-copy-using-cython) about passing over Cython malloc'ed data to Python. I however wonder if casting to a memoryview before returning avoids the memory leak:

```
def someCythonFunction():
    try:
        mPtr = <double *>PyMem_Malloc(N * M * sizeof(double)
        for n in range(N):
            for m in range(M):
                mPtr[m + n*M]= ...
        return <double[:N,:M]> mPtr
    finally:
        print("In cython %d" % <int>mPtr)
        PyMem_Free(mPtr)
```

then in Python:

```
mView = someCythonFunction()
```

Is this safe and correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unsafe and incorrect. It deallocates the memory as the function ends which means the pointer that you return is immediately invalid.

You need to tie the lifetime of the memory to the lifetime of a Python object (as in the example you linked to, the memory is freed in the destructor). The simplest and recommended way of doing this is to use a numpy array or a standard library `array` array (or other library of your choice).

If you can't avoid using `malloc` one option is to use the [`cython.view.array` class](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#cython-arrays). You can assign it a callback function of your choice to use on destruction and it can be happily assigned to memoryviews:

```
cdef double[:,:] mview
cdef double* mPtr = <double *>PyMem_Malloc(N * M * sizeof(double))
a = cython.view.array(shape=(N, M), itemsize=sizeof(double), format="d",
                      mode="C", allocate_buffer=False)
a.data = <char *> mPtr
a.callback_free_data = PyMem_Free

mview = a
```

You can safely return either `a` or `mview` (if you return `a` then there's no need to bother with `mview`) and they will get correctly at the right time.

Comment: This is obvious now that you tell me. I was under the impression that it was working, because although the pointer was freed, data was still accessible and not corrupted in the Python world. But that was probably just a coincidence.