# How do I convert Cython array to Python object so I can return the result?

Tags: python, cython

I'm flabbergasted that there is no documentation on converting a Cython array to a Python object. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

```
# Values are a list of integers containing numerators and denominators 
def test_looping_ndarray_nd_list(list matrix):   

    cdef int *my_ints
    cdef i

    # Allocate memory to store ctype integers in memory 
    my_ints = <int *>malloc(len(matrix)*cython.sizeof(int)) 
    if my_ints is NULL:
        raise MemoryError() 

    for i in xrange(len(matrix)): # Convert to ctypes
        my_ints[i] = matrix[i]

    # How do I convert my_ints to Python object so I can return the result???

    return
```

Comment: I answered your question but don't really have enough context to understand why you want to use a pointer array and malloc for this. If my answer doesn't work for you, please let me know.

By the way, if you *did* somehow return the memory allocated by malloc to python, it would never be freed, so you'd create a memory leak.

Comment: Actually, let me elaborate

Comment: @MLhacker I suspect you're missing the point and you're much better off using a numpy array (with an appropriate dtype) and a memoryview (as Nathan12343 suggests). However, see [this recent question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436046/pass-a-cython-allocated-buffer-to-python/44441467#44441467) for guidance on how to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this using typed memoryviews:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

# Values are a list of integers containing numerators and denominators
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def test_looping_ndarray_nd_list(list matrix):   

    cdef np.intp_t[:] my_ints
    cdef int i

    # Allocate memory to store ctype integers in memory 
    my_ints = np.array(matrix, dtype='int')

    # do some work while releasing the GIL
    with nogil:
        for i in range(my_ints.shape[0]):
            my_ints[i] = 2*my_ints[i]

    return np.asarray(my_ints).tolist()
```

Comment: Actually, let me elaborate. Essentially. I have a Python list with an unknown size I pass to the function. Ultimately I want to manipulate each element of the list and apply nogil. But, first I need to create an array in Ctypes so that's why I'm using the pointer and malloc to achieve my objective.

Comment: Why not just iterate over the list?

Comment: Oh I see, because you can't iterate over a list in a nogil block. I'd still suggest converting your array to typed memoryviews (which can be iterated over in a nogil block). I've modified my answer a bit, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: nathan, what's the purpose of [:] next to the first cdef int declaration?

Comment: Also, with your example I'm getting an error saying "Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got 'long'"

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it will be a bit more portable. np.intp_t is short for "platform-specific int". I *think* that will fix the error you're running into. To answer your first question, the `[:]` syntax declares a 1D typed memoryview: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html.